# Is there a way to plot a scatter plot in highcharter with "jitter", like in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, highcharts, r-highcharter

My doubt is exactly how is written in the title. I am trying to replicate a chart like the one that follows:
[image]

My point is that I need to use highcharter package. So, what I got for while is this:

```R
hcboxplot(x = iris$Sepal.Length,
            var =  iris$Species,
            outliers = FALSE) %>%
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%  # to put box vertical
    hc_size(width = NULL, height = 350) %>%
    hc_add_series(
      data = iris,
      type = "scatter",
      hcaes(x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length", group = "Species")
    )
```

[image]

I want to "jitter" the scatter, like in ggplot2.

Thanks in advance.
Wlademir.

Comment: In the ggplot2 chart what is the xAxis? To me it looks like just 3 categories so what is the xAxis jitter from in ggplot2?

Comment: Here you have a pure JS implementation in Highcharts. Will you manage to put this into R anyhow? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/78fe03wb

Comment: `plotOptions.scatter.jitter` is not available in highcharter, yet. The current highcharter v0.7.0 uses highcharts(.js) v7.0.1 https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/v0.7.0/inst/htmlwidgets/highchart.yaml
`plotOptions.scatter.jitter` was added to highcharts v7.0.2 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.jitter

Comment: I opened a pull request in highcharter to update highcharts to v7.2.0: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/pull/552.